# How to install the cocoapi package on windows required for object detection on tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda, object-detection

I created a conda environment on Anaconda for installing TensorFlow. After that I followed the steps given [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md). After that I faced problems while installing the cocoapi package. So followed instructions from https://github.com/philferriere/cocoapi .

Then while cloning the github file i got the following error:

> error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft
>   Visual  Build Tools":
>   http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

You can find the screenshot of my command prompt window here:[cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZ9pw.jpg)

I have already installed Microsoft C++ Build Tools 2015. I have no idea what to do. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after a couple of rounds it finally worked after performing the following steps:

1- removed previous installation of visual sudio

2- downloaded Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017 from: https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017

3- changed setup.py as explained here:https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi/issues/9

4- wrapped the include statement for maskApi.h in the file _mask.cpp in extern "C" block

```
extern "C" {
#include "maskApi.h"
}
```

Comment: Thanks , but installing the Microsoft 2017 build tools didn&#39;t work , but I installed the 2015 C++ build tools and also downloaded the Windows 8 SDK package and then followed the steps as you mentioned.